# Ruby / Date Parse Hour

Tags: ruby

How do I time parse these strings below:

```
01
02
03
```

So that I can use strftime('%I %p') to make it into:

```
01 AM
02 AM
03 AM
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'date'
DateTime.strptime('01', '%H').strftime('%0l %p')
=> "01 AM"
```

That said, if the string is already '01' why not just stick an AM or PM on it? Can just use `to_i` to determine if it's before/after noon.